# How to get a carrierwave instance giving the attribute name to the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

In my controller I'm trying to do something like:

```
  uploader = object[params[:attribute]]
  uploader.retrieve_from_store!(params[:file])
  uploader.cache_stored_file!
  send_file uploader.file.path
```

But the problem is that `object[params[:attribute]]` is returning a String(the DB record with the filename), not my carrierwave object (I already checked that object.attribute is returning the uploader, it works). How can I get the uploader or maybe how can I initialize it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody crosses with the same problem, I did it with:

```
uploader = object.send(params[:attribute])
```